# How do I install .pl plugins for nagios?

Tags: python, plugins, nagios

I am trying to install the ["check_mssql_sproc.pl"](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Databases/Plugins/SQLServer/check_mssql_sproc/details) plug in for nagios. Where and how do I install it?

Answer (score 3):

Add the command definition to your nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg

Where the pl file is actually installed doesnt matter... just make sure you can run it from the command line and set it up like that in your commands.cfg

Comment: how do you run it from the command line? i can't do ./check_mssql_sproc.pl can i?

Comment: i see. i need to "chmod a+x check_mssql_sproc.pl" it first

Comment: If you're testing a plugin from the command line, be sure to run it as the correct user (probably "nagios"). Otherwise, you'll potentially miss out on environment or permission issues.

Also, another tip - you might find it useful to redirect STDERR to STDOUT in your command definitions, just to save your sanity while trying to configure everything. Just add " 2>&1 " to the end of your command, e.g. /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mssql_sproc.pl (args here) 2>&1".

Trust me, that one tip saved me days of pain. Without it, any errors that the plugin sends to STDERR are not shown in the UI.